# how to avoid changing of ng bootstrap dropdown when enter key is pressed on any on input field in angular13

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

i am using angular powered bootstrap dropdown and here whenever i do enter key press in input, it always changes the dropdown value to first option.

[DEMO LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap-cfwafr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

HTML:

```
<div class="row mb-3 mt-3">
          <div class="col">
            <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                id="dropdownBasic1"
                ngbDropdownToggle
              >
                {{ clickMessage }}
              </button>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                <button
                  ngbDropdownItem
                  class="nav-link"
                  href="#"
                  (click)="getText($event.target.innerText)"
                >
                  Option 1
                </button>
                <button
                  ngbDropdownItem
                  class="nav-link"
                  href="#"
                  (click)="getText($event.target.innerText)"
                >
                  Option 2
                </button>
                <button
                  ngbDropdownItem
                  class="nav-link"
                  href="#"
                  (click)="getText($event.target.innerText)"
                >
                  Option 3
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
  clickMessage = 'Choose an option';

  getText(text) {
    this.clickMessage = text;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is due to you have some buttons without any type attribute and by default the buttons in the form trigger the submit event.Add the type to the buttons in the dropdown and it should work.

```
<div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button
        type="button"
        ngbDropdownItem
        class="nav-link"
        href="#"
        (click)="getText($event, $event.target.innerText)"
    >
        Option 1
    </button>
    <button
        type="button"
        ngbDropdownItem
        class="nav-link"
        href="#"
        (click)="getText($event, $event.target.innerText)"
    >
        Option 2
    </button>
    <button
        ngbDropdownItem
        class="nav-link"
        href="#"
        (click)="getText($event, $event.target.innerText)"
    >
        Option 3
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your ts file.

```
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) public onKeyDown(evt) {
    if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.onSubmit();
    }
  }
```

I write it for you in the following stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap-skiant?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: thanks for response, i want enter keypress to work, so when i click on enter in input, it must perform submit action, but it shouldnt change the dropdown value.

Comment: Do you means you want to submit action when enter press in input but don't change the dropdown ? Am I right?

Comment: I've already updated. Please check it again.